# i18n-tasks cannot route key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rails-i18n, i18n-tasks

My i18n-tasks config file:

```
data:
  read:
    # Default:
     - config/locales/%{locale}.yml
    # More files:
     - config/locales/**/*.%{locale}.yml
     - config/locales/views/*.{locale}.yml
     - config/locales/models/*.{locale}.yml
     - config/locales/helpers/*.{locale}.yml

  # Locale files to write new keys to, based on a list of key pattern => file rules. Matched from top to bottom:
  # `i18n-tasks normalize -p` will force move the keys according to these rules
  write:
      # write models.* and views.* keys to the respective files,
      - ['{models,views,helpers}.*', 'config/locales/\1.%{locale}.yml']
```

When I type `i18n-tasks add-missing` in console, I have error:
`i18n-tasks: Cannot route key objects.no_objects_yet Routes are [["{models,views,helpers}.*", "config/locales/\\1.%{locale}.yml"]]`

What I should edit to add-missing params? I want every add-missing translation to views/{viewname}/en.yml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stock mechanism routes unknown key names to file paths. Because `objects.no_objects_yet` does not match any pattern (`{models,views,helpers}.*`), it cannot route it. You could write a custom router to work around that ([implementation](https://github.com/glebm/i18n-tasks/tree/master/lib/i18n/tasks/data/router), [documentation](https://github.com/glebm/i18n-tasks#multiple-locale-files)).

However, note that many views are likely to share keys. When a key is strictly specific to a given view, what you could do instead is name the key with the view name, e.g.:

```
<%= 'my_view.title' %>
```

Then, have the following route:

```
- ['{:}.*', 'config/locales/\1.%{locale}.yml']
```

This will route the unknown keys based on the first part of each key, e.g. the key above will be routed to `config/locales/my_view.en.yml`.